# Jaspersoft Hive date parameter issue

Tags: hadoop, hive, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I am using JasperSoft Studio to connect to Hive and pass a query with a dynamic date.  The report should be querying on yesterdays date.  I am having an issue with using a dynamic in the JasperSoft Studio Dataset and Query Dialog box.  The following query works from the Hive command line, but JasperSoft Studio does not seem to recognize the commands "date_sub" and "unix_timestamp()".  I am using JasperSoft Studio version 6.1.

```
SELECT col1, count(col2), count(col3)
FROM table1
WHERE date = date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd'),1)
GROUP BY col1
```

Any suggestions as to how to get this query to work would be greatly appreciated, if a date parameter can be passed in an alternative way using JasperSoft's paramters or variables I would be open to that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution will be create a **view** on your DDBB and make a basic sql on JasperSoft to access the information.